# What is the 'Ctrl + Alt + NumPad+' cursor in MS Word 2007?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2007, cursor

While doodling in MS Word (as you do) I hit the 'Ctrl + Alt + NumPad+' keyboard short cut which changed my cursor to the one shown below (similar to the Mac 'Command' key symbol):

[image]

The cursor doesn't seem to behave any differently to the usual cursor and it reverts to normal if you hit the 'Esc' key.

Anyone know what this is all about?

(I'm on Windows 7, 64bit, UK keyboard, Word 2007)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num-Plus</kbd> initializes up the keyboard customizer.

Try performing some action with your mouse (setting the font colour, for example). After you perform the action, you can then assign that action to a shortcut key for later re-use.

For more information, see [the Microsoft Office community.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/what-does-ctrl-alt-do/500ab112-5868-4a4c-baa7-ab4cc3ebd8c4)

Comment: Aha! You learn something every day :¬)